# Short-cutting version of `select` for no more than n matches

Tags: ruby, lazy-evaluation

I need to return the first three elements of

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8].select{|e| e % 2 == 0}
```

which is `[2, 4, 6]`, without trying `7` and `8`. I would expect it to take the form

```
select_some([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 3){|e| e % 2 == 0}
```

I have a solution as follows:

```
def select_some(array, n, &block)
  gather = []
  array.each do |e|
    next unless block.call e
    gather << e
    break if gather.size >= n
  end
  gather
end
```

but is there something built-in to Ruby that performs this short-cutting? Please don't suggest I patch a method onto arrays to achieve `array.select_some`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a lazy collection. Something like:

`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8].lazy.select { |a| a.even? }.take(3)`

You'll get an `Enumerator::Lazy` back, but you can use `to_a` or `force` when you need the data.

Comment: You can also use `first(3)` instead of `take(3)` to get an array.

Comment: When I inspect the return value of above expression, why it returns an enumerator instead of array?  It works when I use `first(3)`

Comment: @WandMaker because `take` is lazy, too.

Comment: Great. Thanks very much!